# emulator won't start, with segmentation fault error

Tags: android, emulation

guys.  I am new to Android app development and I encountered some issue when I tried to start the emulator.  I tried to start the emulator from the Android Virtual Device Manager, and nothing happened.  There's no pop-up, no error message.  I tried it from the command line and it showed a one-line output, which is "Segmentation fault".  I created different virtual devices but they all failed to start with the same error output.
My OS is Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit, and the Android SDK is r20.0.3-linux.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try with: `emulator -gpu on @youremulatorname`

Comment: Hi, Dadaista. Thanks for the reply.  I tried the command and the emulator showed up with blank screen.  I waited for 30 minutes and it was still blank.  I tried the command on different virtual machine and got the blank screen on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I also seen the same kind of prob. Normally i guess emulator depends on RAM, as it interacts faster. So try swapping your RAM.

For my friend emulator worked after changing RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Satheesh.  The computer has 2G memory, but I don't have extra memory.  What I did was put the memory in different slots, but it ended up with same error.  I have multiple OS installed in the computer.  When I tried the emulator in WindowsXP, it works.  I am not sure if the problem is caused by the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mv tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so.xxx
```

(taken from [Android emulator segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997771/android-emulator-segmentation-fault))

Comment: Not actually, you need to rename all the lib*.* to lib*.*.xxx if you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

following edit in the **.android/avd/{avd name}.ini** file fix this problem for me.

```
hw.gpu.mode=auto
hw.gpu.enabled = no
```