# Android emulator segmentation fault

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

Running it from the command line resulted in a segmentation fault:

```
$ emulator -avd nexus_s
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, running emulator-arm directly as follows, works fine.

```
$ emulator-arm -avd nexus_s
```

I suspect it's trying to run the mips or x86 version of the emulator.
Is there a way to configure the emulator which executable to start?

All this started after updating to android sdk 17.

Adding the -verbose flag gives the following output (which I don't think adds any info):

```
$ emulator -verbose -avd nexus_s
emulator: found SDK root at /opt/sdk
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 17
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 480x800
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 480x800
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/grebulon/.android/default.keyset
emulator: found magic skin width=480 height=800 bpp=16

emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /opt/sdk/system-images/android-17/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /opt/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-17/images/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /opt/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-17/images/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 343MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 343
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = no
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 240
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = yes
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 32
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = /opt/sdk/system-images/android-17/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = /opt/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-17/images/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /opt/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-17/images/armeabi-v7a//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 209m
  avd.name = nexus_s
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/opt/sdk/tools/emulator64-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "/home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /opt/sdk/tools/emulator64-arm -android-hw /home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd    /hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,initfile=/opt/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-17/images/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-grebulon/emulator-RSuUtb
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xd100000,file=/home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now d116000

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '32m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/grebulon/.android/avd/nexus_s.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: OS X? Linux? Some strange parallel-universe version of Windows where they too adopted the `$` command prompt?

Comment: Linux, ubuntu 12.04 to be specific.

Comment: Try adding `-v` to the `emulator` command line and see where it dumps. I had a problem with `emulator` on the R21 Android tools crashing when trying to load an OpenGL driver on Ubuntu 11.10 -- there's an issue about it on b.android.com, where the workaround is to rename that OpenGL driver so Android can't find it.

Comment: Before I tried the command-line, the AVD manager would say it is starting the device, but no window would show up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I finally found a solution after following CommonsWare's tip.
Renaming libOpenglRender.so made the problem go away.

```
mv tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so.xxx
```

Comment: This does make the emulator show up. but It outputs the following error message: emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! After more than a week trying everything here and there renaming all the lib*.* files from <sdk-installation-folder>/tools/lib/ to lib*.*.xxx made the emulator to start. I was right, all the emulator crashing issue was related to OpenGLES: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33336 & https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28601

Comment: For 64 bit rename the lib64OpenglRender.so to lib64OpenglRender.so.xxx file.

Comment: When I try this it takes for ever to load the AVD and it's like running it with the ```-gpu off``` option so don't know if it actually solves the problem... anyway we can get it to run fast without using the buggy openGL renderer?

Comment: Don't make the same stupid mistake as me, calling `${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/emulator` instead of `${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/emulator`. The first one segfaulted on my machine and I wasted some time before I realized the second path was working.

Answer (score 5):

Paste  to ~/.android/avd/.avd/config.ini

```
hw.gpu.mode = swiftshader_indirect
```

I solved it this way in my case.

Comment: weird. I tried this and some variations of the pathname, but the option `hw.gpu.mode = host` never had success while `-gpu host` worked (the file didn't exist on my machine, I even had to create the .avd directory)

Answer (score 4):

On my Ubuntu 12.04 system, I solved this problem by making sure "Use Host GPU" was not turned on in the AVD configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but since it's coming up when I search for this error, I figured I'd post my solution.

I ran my emulator from the terminal using `emulator -avd Pixel_7_API_31_S_ -gpu off` to test to make sure it was a GPU issue. In doing so, I noticed that the terminal output was giving me warnings about my emulator needing to be updated. Updating fixed the overall issue.

1. Go to `Tools > SDK Manager`, then to the `SDK Tools` tab.
2. Find `Android Emulator` in the list and change it to a checkmark (mine was a dash).
3. Click the `OK` button.

Comment: This worked for me. I hadn't change my AVD in a while (~2yrs), and had to update the emulator for the newest AVD / API.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04. Renaming libOpenglRender.so was working for me, but the emulator was taking forever to initialize. Also, I had to reinstall Ubuntu (for different reasons), and then I started getting the `emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library` error when opening the emulator.

After searching more about those issues, I found out that the problem was with the video driver. I was using the Nouveau's, and after changing to an Nvidia driver, I no longer had to keep libOpenglRender.so renamed, and now the emulator initializes very fast without showing any error message.

This is the driver that fixed the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to copy the `libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4` file to the SDK directory:

```
cp /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 emulator/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Debian Wheezy. The grebulon's answer kind-of worked for me, however the emulator was sloooooow so I set out to fix it The Right Way (tm).

**In this case `Segmentation fault` probably indicates problems with OpenGL.**
(note that last line of log is "emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support")

In my case, searching for 'GL' through `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` showed some NVidia GLX driver (from old video card which went to digital heaven). Given the fact that I have AMD Radeon I uninstalled every package with 'nvidia' in it (list: `apt-get search nvidia | grep ^i`) and installed:

```
# apt-get install libgl1-fglrx-glx
```

After reboot emulator complained about missing `libOpenglRender.so` and `libGL.so`, which I solved like this:

```
# echo "/opt/adt/sdk/tools/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/android_stuff.conf
# ldconfig
# cd /opt/adt/sdk/tools/lib
# ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 libGL.so
```

Note that my situation is probably unique (problems started when I went from NVidia to AMD), but the root of the problem is probably similar (OpenGL). I hope it helps someone.

UPDATE: still doesn't work, it looks like my drivers do not support 16-bit colors in OpenGL... will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the answer here you should subscribe to:

1. [Issue 34233: Emulator start produces segmentation fault after upgrading to r20](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34233)
2. [Issue 55325: Emulator crashing with segfault](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55325)
3. [Issue 20952: Emulator segfault on startup (unrelated to audio)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20952)

There you will receive updates about this issue and find some workarounds (like renaming lib*.* files).

Answer (score 0):

wiping data and cold booting device through android studio solved this issue in ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in an lxc environment. After getting

```
./Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I had success with option

```
./Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 -no-qt
```

This is a headless mode (no window at all, so don't be surprised). It showed me that the problem was in the graphical representation.

I then found that `-gpu auto`, `-gpu swiftshader_indirect` and `-gpu guest` failed, while `-gpu host` worked.

So, the final line on my machine is:

```
./Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 -gpu host
```

To make this persistent, I had to add it to `~/.android/avd/Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64.avd/config.ini`, thanks to DARUMA:

```
$ tail ~/.android/avd/Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64.avd/config.ini 

hw.gpu.mode = host
```

Answer (score -1):

Type command

**$ emulator-arm @nexus_s**

Hope this helps :-)