# Android tools abort with a 'segmentation fault'

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I've updated to Android SDK revision 21.1 and to Android NDK r8e.
Using Ubuntu 12.10 (inside a vimware on top of a Windows 7 host.)

Every time I run some tool from the platform tools or NDK tools I'm getting a segmentation fault as a response.
A `segmentation fault` message is printed on the terminal. When I check the returned error code (`echo $?`) I get 139 (which also means a segmentation fault).

Among the tools that I tried are `adb` and `ndk-build`

I tried to remove everything related to the SDK and NDK and downloaded them all again but got the same result.

I'm really frustrated, already spent few days digging the internet but found nothing.

Has anybody encountered this problem?

Comment: I think we need a lot more information before we can help. What exactly is printed on the terminal? If you use something like `strace adb` what information do you get?

Comment: I'll do that once I'll be at work.

Comment: Are you trying to run a emulator related tool? Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997771/android-emulator-segmentation-fault)? Are you able to execute `adb shell`?

Comment: I wrote that I cannot run any of the adb variants. It doesn't matter whether it's on real device or emulator - as I said - even the ndk-build command doesn't work. About the link - maybe it will help - I'll let you know if so.

Comment: Have you tried running the same actions directly in Windows ? And directly on Ubuntu 12.10 ? So you rule out the vm/win interaction ?

Comment: In the windows host it's working well.

Comment: I just saw this accidentally - add @<username_here> for the other user to be notified of your comment. Try also in vanilla Ubuntu and then go and bug either them or the vm people - vm's are mostly to blame in those scenarios

Comment: Please run: `gdb --args adb shell`, then `run` then, when it crashes, `bt`. Add the output here. Of course, you may need first to `sudo apt-get install gdb`.