# absolutely nothing happens when I start emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to start working on Android and for that i downloaded `Android ADT Bundle`.I have created an AVD and when I start Absolutely nothing happens. When I click on start , a window appears saying starting emulator and then after some time it vanishes and nothing happens. No error code, no message, no pop-up window nothing .nothing. And when I clicked on delete AVD, I got an error message :

This Emulator is currently running and cannot be deleted.

I am working on linux 12.04.

Comment: this will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow

Comment: i tried starting from terminal , it gave an error saying segmentation fault (Core dumped)

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997771/android-emulator-segmentation-fault

Comment: Please restart your system and check if it helps. After that still issues, delete the current AVD n create the new one. Sometimes,abnormalities expected

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is for Linux, but I have a similar problem on Windows so.

I know that it's a little bit late, but for others who have the same problem. I got this solution.

You have to run the emulator but prompt, go to the sdk/emulator and run:

`emulator -avd 'name-of-avd' -verbose`

It will show you wich is the the location you have to run to see wich .dll is missing.

So you do to the shown directory and run the same, in my case:

`qemu-system-aarch64.exe -avd -NoSkin - verbose`

Install the missing .dll and also copy the emulators .dll located at `Sdk\emulator\lib\qt\lib` to the system32 directory.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the memory that you allocated for that particular AVD.

[image]

Memory options as shown in figure, should have a value smaller than the memory you allocated while installing HAXM/AVD. Its optimal to keep it 512MB. This may be the reason your emulator isnt starting. Check if you have set the SDK path right (Preferences->Android->SDK)